# When printing base64 conversion, I receive numbers instead of characters

Tags: python

I have an image that I have encoded into a base64 String. When I print this string I get something like: "4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAA..." as expected. However, if I iterate over the string in a for loop, I get an output of numbers, like: 88, 66, 32, 11, etc.

So why is it converting the base64 into a number when I print a character, but not the actual item at the index?

```
import base64
with open("mexico.jpg", "rb") as img_file:
    my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())

myList = []
for i in range(len(my_string)):
  myList.append(my_string[i])
  print(my_string[i])
  if i % 10 == 0:
    print(myList)
    myList = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the integer you're seeing to a char. Instead of `my_string[i]`, try `chr(my_string[i])`

Comment: You're the best!